# How could I deserialize the data from API without using JSON namespaces or libraries

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Recently I got a test from a company which requires me to deal with some data got from an RESTful API in C#, and I was not allowed to use my own IDE to finish the test, I failed because I really had no idea about how to deserialize the json data got from the API without using any json namespace.

I even couldn't use DataContractJsonSerializer to create the classes to deserialize the JSON data.

How could I get the data deserialize using these namespaces please (I was not allowed to add any other namespace)?

for example, if I want to use JsonConvert to desterilize the data received from the API , I have to add
`using Newtonsoft.Json;`
but I was not allowed to do this.

All the namespaces it provided are:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
```

How can I get the data received from the API and deserialize it into JSON using the provided namespace above.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string apiAddress = "..../api/user";
var data = client.DownloadData(apiAddress);
```

I just remembered that when the website compile the code, it used this command:
**-r:/usr/lib/cli/Newtonsoft.Json-5.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll**

But I used the JsonConvert, there was compilation error.

I tried to split the data, but the time was not enough for me to do so.

Comment: Not allowed, why?

Comment: because the using namespace part is not allowed to edit, only the method part.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to add

```
using  Newtonsoft.Json;
```

before the class. As the compile error message shows it is using Newtonsoft.

I haven't tried the extern alias, it might be also a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Newtonsoft.Json  (Json.net) is the gold standard to use, but Microsoft has a Serialization Namespace that provides the DataContractJsonSerializer.

Below is how you can use that class to deserialize a Json string into a object.

```
//using System.Runtime.Serialization;
//Deserialization using DataContractJsonSerializer

string json = "imagine json is here";

DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SomeObject));
var encoding = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(endoding);

SomeObject someObject = (someObject)js.ReadObject(ms);
```